# How to load local HTML files in Xamarin Forms WebView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I intend to load local HTML files into a Xamarin Forms WebView.

I've added the HTML files to the `assets/HTML` folder, and its Build Action is set to AndroidAsset.

I've implemented the base URL finder interface:

```
public class BaseUrl_Android:IBaseUrl
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "file:///android_asset/";
        }
    }
```

I have tried to load the file from the using this in the shared portable code:

```
   string baseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();
   string url = baseUrl + "HTML/local.html";
   myWebView.Source = url;
```

I also tried a custom WebViewRenderer, and used this code:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            // lets get a reference to the native control
            var webView = (global::Android.Webkit.WebView)Control;
            // do whatever you want to the WebView here!                                
            webView.LoadUrl(DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get()+"HTML/local.html");
            webView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        }
```

With both solutions I get an error:

[image]

What else should I try?

Answer (score 0):

Your source should be of type HtmlWebViewSource and not string.

```
var html = new HtmlWebViewSource ();
html.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl> ().Get ();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my MainActivity.cs;

```
WebView web_view;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    web_view = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
    web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

    web_view.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/Home.html");

}
```

You must put your html file in to Assets folder and sets html build action AndroidAsset. With this way I can load html file into WebView.

Comment: Your solution is based on working template, asked question belongs to "Blank App(Xamarin.Forms Portable)"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you had trouble.
I followed your steps and things just worked:

The snippet looks like this:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    var rootUrl = DependencyService.Get<INativeURL>().Acquire();
    Url = $"{rootUrl}content.html";
}
```

**NOTE:**

"Content.html" is the name of my local webpage that I added to the "Assets" folder of my local Droid project.

**XAML**

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<WebView Source="{Binding Url}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

**ViewModel:**

```
    public ViewModel()
    {
        var rootUrl = DependencyService.Get<INativeURL>().Acquire();
        Url = $"{rootUrl}content.html";
    }

    string _url = null;
    public string Url
    {
        get
        {
            return _url;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_url != value)
            {
                _url = value;
                OnNotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Interface:**

```
public interface INativeURL
{
    string Acquire();
}
```

**Android Contract:**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(NativeURL_Android))]
namespace my_namespace.Droid
{
    public class NativeURL_Android : INativeURL
    {
        public string Acquire() => "file:///android_asset/";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the DependencyService? is it class? if yes then where i have to create and what content i have to write in it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is related post and official sample

See if this can help.

[Xamarin load local html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055244/how-to-load-a-local-html-file-in-a-xamrian-forms-webview/43268968#43268968)

and

[Official sample here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithWebview)

```
public LocalHtmlBaseUrl ()
    {
        var browser = new BaseUrlWebView (); // temporarily use this so we can custom-render in iOS

        var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource ();

        htmlSource.Html = @"<html>...</html>";

        htmlSource.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl> ().Get ();


        browser.Source = htmlSource;

        Content = browser;
    }
```

Comment: Add sample link!