# How to load a local html file in a xamarin forms webview

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to load a html file that is in the same path as class i'm working with Via a web view in xamarin forms when I run the app I get a white screen and nothing loads here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App.Plan
{
    public partial class Tornado : ContentPage
    {
        public Tornado()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var browser = new WebView
            {
                Source = "local.html"
};
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you refer to the documentation, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/webview/  Says to place in the Resources folder for iOS/ Assets Folder for Android and remember to set your build action to BundleResource for iOS and AndroidAsset for Android

Comment: I have done this and am still getting the same issue any other suggestions? Thanks for the fast reply! :)

Comment: To load a local html file for web view you have to set the BaseUrl Property to tell the web view what prefix to use to resolve files.  You would need to do this on each platform.  So where are your platform specific implementations of accessing that path and the local HTML file?  What you have posted would work if you were calling an internet site which would get translated into a UrlWebViewSource , local.html would not translate hence why you see nothing.

Comment: @Bearcat9425 thanks for the reply I understand what your saying but I am fairly new to c# can you please give me a example on what your suggesting me to do? Thanks :)

Comment: read this https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/ it shows for all3 platforms

Comment: The link I provided in the first comment has Exactly what you are looking for as far as examples are concerned. Pulling from web page, loading HTML as string, and also loading a local HTML from the OS.

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is old, but the documentation is maybe not entirely clear when it comes to local files so I thought I'd share my thoughts.  Hopefully it's helpful to anyone who stumbles here.

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview) states:

> To display local content using a WebView, you'll need to open the HTML file like any other, then load the contents as a string into the Html property of an HtmlWebViewSource.

The key thing to note is that the WebView's *Source* property is ONLY for external URLs or HtmlWebViewSource.  You cannot put a local URL in the Source property.  The phrasing *"you'll need to open the HTML file like any other"* means (as it states shortly after) that you need to load the contents of the file from disk into a variable using a full file path, not URL.

The question then becomes "What about links to other local files?"  That's where the BaseUrl property of HtmlWebViewSource comes into play.  The documentation addresses this by stating the following:

> Although the first page has been loaded, the WebView has no knowledge of where the HTML came from. That is a problem when dealing with pages that reference local resources. Examples of when that might happen include when local pages link to each other, a page makes use of a separate JavaScript file, or a page links to a CSS stylesheet.

In other words, any links to local resources in your HTML will be prepended with the BaseUrl by the Webview automatically.

**To sum things up**

Create the IBaseUrl Interface in your shared project

```cs
public interface IBaseUrl { 
    string Get(); 
}
```

Create the platform-specific implementations of IBaseUrl in each platform project

iOS:

```cs
[assembly: Dependency (typeof (BaseUrl_iOS))]
namespace WorkingWithWebview.iOS
{
  public class BaseUrl_iOS : IBaseUrl
  {
    public string Get()
    {
      return NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
    }
  }
}
```

Android

```cs
[assembly: Dependency (typeof(BaseUrl_Android))]
namespace WorkingWithWebview.Android
{
  public class BaseUrl_Android : IBaseUrl
  {
    public string Get()
    {
      return "file:///android_asset/";
    }
  }
}
```

UWP

```cs
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BaseUrl))]
namespace WorkingWithWebview.UWP
{
    public class BaseUrl : IBaseUrl
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "ms-appx-web:///";
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure your HTML files are in the appropriate folders and have the proper Build Action

- iOS: Resources, build action: "BundleResource"
- Android: Assets, build action: "AndroidAsset"
- UWP: project root, build action: "content"

Make sure the WebView has a height and width request or it may not render:

> It may be necessary to set the WidthRequest and HeightRequest properties of the WebView to see the HTML content, depending upon the layout the WebView is a child of. For example, this is required in a StackLayout.

Once that setup is done, you can put it into action in your shared project.  Here's a simplified example:

```cs
// Use DI function to get the BaseUrl for the platform
var baseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();

// You could append subfolders here if you don't 
// want all the HTML files mixed with other resources:
// var baseUrl = System.IO.Path.Combine(DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get(), "subfolder");

// Define the location of your initial HTML page using the base url
var initialHtmlPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(baseUrl, "index.html");

// Create the viewsource, loading the first HTML file as a string
var localHtmlViewSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
localHtmlViewSource.BaseUrl = baseUrl;
localHtmlViewSource.Html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(initialHtmlPath);

// Set the webview to use the local source
HelpWebView.Source = localHtmlViewSource;
```

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin has docs in relation to this:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/

```
var browser = new WebView();
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
htmlSource.Html = @"<html><body>
  <h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
  <p>Welcome to WebView.</p>
  </body></html>";
browser.Source = htmlSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is official sample in github

[WorkingWithWebview](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithWebview)

```
tabs.Children.Add (new LocalHtml {Title = "Local" });
tabs.Children.Add (new LocalHtmlBaseUrl {Title = "BaseUrl" });
tabs.Children.Add (new WebPage { Title = "Web Page"});
tabs.Children.Add (new WebAppPage {Title ="External"});
```

Second tab may help.